# Ruby - Check if controller defined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, solidus

I am using Solidus with Ruby on Rails to create a webshop and I have multiple modules for that webshop.

So, I defined a me controller into an module called 'solidus_jwt_auth' with the followin code:

```
module Spree
  module Api
    class MeController < Spree::Api::BaseController
      def index
        ...
      end

      def orders
        ...
      end

      def addresses
        ...
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I want to extend this in another module called 'solidus_prescriptions' so I created a decorator for this with the following code `me_decorator`:

```
if defined? Spree::Api::MeController.class
  Spree::Api::MeController.class_eval do
    def prescriptions
      ...
    end

    def create_prescription
      ...
    end

    private

    def prescription_params
      params.require(:prescription).permit(
          *Spree::CustomerPrescription.permitted_attributes
      )
    end
  end
end
```

And for this I wrote unit tests in solidus_prescription module and integration tests in webshop. The unit tests are working fine, but the integration tests are giving the following error:

**Error:
MeEndpointsTest#test_me/prescriptions_post_endpoint_throws_an_error_when_wrong_params:
AbstractController::ActionNotFound: The action 'create_prescription' could not be found for Spree::Api::MeController
    test/integration/me_endpoints_test.rb:68:in `block in '**

Which means that he can not find the MeController defined in another module. How can I make the check if the MeController is defined since the code bellow does not help me with anything:

```
if defined? Spree::Api::MeController.class
end
```

Comment: It cannot find the defined method within you class_eval's block. How are you calling the decorator to add these methods? You should use a module to include them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked in the end:

```
def class_defined?(klass)
  Object.const_get(klass)
rescue
  false
end

if class_defined? 'Spree::Api::MeController'
 ....
end
```

Answer (score 1):

`if defined?` should do exactly what you want it to do in theory. The problem is you're checking `if defined? Spree::Api::MeController.class`. The `#class` of your class is `Class`. So what you're really getting is `if defined? Class` which will always be true!

This issue is most likely not that the conditional is failing but that it's never getting read. Rails lazy loads most of the code you write, meaning the file is not read until it's called somewhere in execution.

The decorator module should just contain the methods you want to add, without the conditionals or the use of `class_eval`. Then in the original `class` you can include it.

```
module Spree
  module Api
    class MeController < Spree::Api::BaseController
      include MeDecorator
    end
  end
end
```

If for any reason you're not certain `MeDecorator` will be defined, don't use `defined?`, because `defined? MeDecorator` will not actually go looking for it if it's not defined and load the necessary file. It will return `nil` if the constant has no value. Just `rescue` a `NameError`

```
module Spree
  module Api
    class MeController < Spree::Api::BaseController
      begin
        include MeDecorator
      rescue NameError => e
        logger.error e
      end
    end
  end
end
```